# How to find the perimeter of a rectangle and an scalene triangle?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{21 cm}\\
2.&\textrm{39 cm}\\
3.&\textrm{28 cm}\\
4.&\textrm{27 cm}\\
\end{array}$

I've attempted to follow a similar strategy of assigning values to the edges of the figures mentioned.

This was done as follows:

Since it was mentioned that the figure is a square then this means that the edges measure 6 cm.

Assuming that the inner sides of the scalene triangle are $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$ and $6$ (this starting from the left in clockwise direction).

This leads to:

$a+b+c+d+6=15$

The upper segment which has been cut by the triangle I'm assigning those as:
$e,\,f,\,g$. (These starting from the left to the right).

Thus $e+f+g=6$

Up here the perimeter of the orange shaded region would be.

$3\times 6 + a+b+c+d = P$

Thus $a+b+c+d=9$

Therefore:

$P=18+9=27\,cm$

Therefore this should be the perimeter. But does it exist a better way than doing this?. Can it be obtained in a faster way?.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the calculations, at least, by thinking of it this way:

The perimeter of the orange shape consists of three sides of the square, along with two of the sides of the triangle. In particular, it consists of
$$(\text{perimeter of triangle})+(\text{perimeter of square})-2\times (\text{side of square}).$$
So, the answer is
$$15+24-2\cdot\frac{24}{4}=27\text{ cm}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the orange region's border contains three sides of the square (three quarters of the square's perimeter), plus the entire triangle's border, *except* for the bottom side of the square. Thus the answer is $\frac3424+15-\frac1424=\frac1224+15=12+15=27$.